# Azure - Attach a system disk to a Linux VM

Tags: hard-drive, mount, azure, linux-on-azure

Say I have VM-A and VM-B two Linux systems on Azure, both belonging to different resource groups.

Is it possible that I stop VM-A and attach its system disk to VM-B, mounting it as a normal disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot attach the VM-A system disk to VM-B even if the VM-A is in the stopped state.

If you want to attach the VM-A system disk to VM-B, you should delete the VM-A so that the disk is free and can attach to other VMs in the same region.